# How to make MouseEvent "wasHeld" property work?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, qml

I have a simple `MouseArea` where I'm trying to detect drag actions. Everything seemes to work fine, but wasHeld property somehow allways going false. Am I using it wrong way, or it's just broken?

```
MouseArea {
    id: mousearea
    property bool dragging: false
    // ...
    onPressed: {
    // ...
                dragging = true;
    // ...
    }
    onReleased: {
        if (mouse.wasHeld) { // allways false
            dragging = false;
            status.text = "was held - stop dragging";
        } else {
            points.add(mouseX, mouseY); canvas.drawPoint(mouseX,mouseY);
            status.text = "wasn`t held - add point";
        }
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        if (dragging) {
            // ...
            canvas.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another simple way to recognize whether mouse was held or not?

UPD: solved by timing onPressed signal.

Comment: Isn't it suitable for you to use the `Drag` attached property of the draggable `Item` and to define a `DropArea` to handle all drag and drop events?